# regular expressions for file_get_content

Tags: php

I'm using exchange currency api for get current dollar rate. Following using PHP code for get content, but after print is in brackets,

```
$url = "http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/currency?from=USD&to=PKR&q=1";

$result = file_get_contents($url);
echo $result;


// print as {"to": "PKR", "rate": 103.59473699999999, "from": "USD", "v": 103.59473699999999}
```

How to make regular expression to get only dollar rate.

Comment: This looks like JSON. try `json_decode()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/currency?from=USD&to=PKR&q=1 is returning you JSON.
Below should help you:

```
$fc = file_get_contents("http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/currency?from=USD&to=PKR&q=1");
$json = json_decode($fc, true);
echo $json['rate'];
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need regular expressions here. The answer you are getting back from the API looks like it's in a JSON format.

What you'll want to do is execute a `json_decode()` function on the return value:

```
$result = file_get_contents( $url );
$data = json_decode( $result, true )
```

Now you'll have an associative array inside the `$data` object. You'll be able to access it using the same syntax as associative arrays:

```
echo $data[ "to" ] // PKR
echo $data[ "rate" ] // 103.59473699999999
echo $data[ "from" ] // USD
echo $data[ "v" ] // 103.59473699999999
```

References:

- [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use regexp then it would be something like:

```
/"rate"\s*\:\s*"([0-9\.]+)/
```

anyway your example looks like json, I'd rather suggest to use it this way:

```
$data = json_decode($contents);
echo $data->rate;
```

Comment: No - the OP doesn't really want to use regular expressions for this.

Comment: The question is "How to make regular expression" so I'm not sure. ;)

Comment: The OP might *think* that this is what they want... but we know otherwise :P

Comment: Thats why I wrote what I wrote ;)

Answer (score 1):

The result you're getting from the API looks like `JSON`, it cannot/shouldn't be parsed with (vanilla) regular expressions; `PHP` already has [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):

```
$decoded = json_decode($result);
echo $decoded->rate;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use json_decode on your file_get_contents result using true as second parameter, then access to your rate as the "rate" key in the result array.

```
$r = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
echo $r["rate"];
```

thats it